# OPENCV_PYTHON_IMAGE2VIDEO GENERATION Error

Tags: python, opencv

I got following error while converting image frames to video--

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/video_writer", line 25, in 
    cv.WriteFrame(writer,frames[i])
TypeError: Argument 'image' must be IplImage

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

How to get this iplimage????

I used cv.writer(writer,frames[i])
where frames[] is an array of images ie

frames=['c:\jay....',................'c:\jay.....']

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Did you verify that everything in "frames" (assuming that is the image argument) is of type IplImage?

Comment: If this question has been successfully answered, consider selecting the official answer by clicking on the checkbox near it. If not, consider adding your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

For what I can tell from your code,

```
frames=['c:\jay....',................'c:\jay.....']
```

the declaration resembles an array of strings, and `strings != IplImage` , agree?

You can have an `IplImage` when you load an image from the disk using `cvLoadImage()`:

```
frame = cvLoadImage("some_image.jpg")
if not frame:
    print "Could not load frame from the disk"
```